# Double Summation Simplification - How to simplify the below summation formula with powers of 2?

Tags: summation

I need help in simplifying the below double summation.

$\sum_{j=1}^i  \sum_{k=i}^n  (k-j+1) (2^{\max(j-2,0)})(2^{\max(n-k-1,0)})$

Comment: Since this is not continuous sort of, I'd split it up into multiple sums, depending on the cases for you exponents.

Comment: I tried splitting up but I'm getting an incorrect solution. I think I'm doing something wrong while simplifying. That's why I ended up posting the question here.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{j=1}^i  \sum_{k=i}^n  (k-j+1) (2^{\max(j-2,0)})(2^{\max(n-k-1,0)}) = \sum_{j=1}^i 2^{\max{j-2}, 0}(1+\sum_{k=i}^{n-1}2^{n-k-1}
=\sum_{j=1}^i 2^{\max{j-2}, 0} (1+\sum_{m=0}{n-1-i} 2^m)
=\sum_{j=1}^i 2^{\max{j-2}, 0} ( 2^{n-1}-2^i)
=(2+\sum_{k=0}^{i-2} 2^k)(2^{n-1}-2^i)).$$

Comment: It can actually be more simplified to `S = 3*2^(n-1)-2^(n-i)-2^(i-1)`. But I'm not able to get this result.